# Looking for a short story my father read years ago-curved part of space and goes back in time

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

A lookout ship hits curved space and gets transported back in time.  It flies back to Earth and tries to call in but no one answers.  He lands out in western USA somewhere and finds work.  The guy is in a bar telling his coworker about being from the future.

He hit a part of curved space and went back in time and the Terraforming ship that was following must have gone further back in time.